# How to implement animation on page load for react app

Tags: reactjs, animation

[image: Animation]I want to implement animation on page load for my app, and I want it to be as in the example below (on photo). I see this animation quite often now on many websites (including gitbook). This animation shows loading elements of a page (like titles, paragraphs, etc.) as blinking rectangulars. Does anyone know if I need to implement it from scratch or are there any libraries to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Sematic Ui Placeholder](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/placeholder/)